# Powermock throwing Class Not Found Exception for Test class

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am using PowerMock with Ant build and Spring 3.0. When I used `SpringJunit4ClassRunner` annotation the test runs fine. But when I implemented `PowermockRunner` (1.6.5)  with a `PowerMockRunnerDelegate`, the runner was not able to detect the Testing class itself.

```
@Named("teskListTest")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:conf/TestBeans.xml"})
@PrepareForTest(SysList.class)
public class SysListTest {  

SysList sysList;

@Test
public void addSysWithIdTest() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("SysListTest : Entering addSysWithIdTest ");

    java.util.logging.Logger log = Mockito.mock(java.util.logging.Logger.class);
    sysList = new SysList(log);
    Component comp = Mockito.mock(Component.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Component.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(comp);
    sysList.test();
    Mockito.verify(comp).getId();

    System.out.println("sysListTest : Exiting addsysWithIdTest");
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
[junit] Running com.example.unittest.SystemTestSuite
[junit] Testsuite: com.example.unittest.SystemTestSuite
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.02 sec
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.02 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: initializationError took 0.002 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] com.example.tasktest.SysListTest
[junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tasktest.SysListTest
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:219)
[junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:161)
[junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:48)
[junit]     at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:113)
[junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:71)
[junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
[junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
[junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
[junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
[junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
[junit]
[junit] Test com.example.unittest.TaskTestSuite FAILED
```

I tried using Mockito 1.9.5, 1.10.16. Tried using PowerMock jar with version 1.6.1 and 1.6.5 and Junit 4.12, 4.11. The exception never changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks  like your production classes are not part of the test class path. I think the problem is your `build.xml`. Please have a look at JUnit's ["Getting started – Ant"](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started-%E2%80%93-Ant) article.